# Cloud Run Error 504 (Upstream Request Timeout) after successful deploy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-shell

I was following this tutorial from Google to deploy a servise to Cloud Run (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-run-hello-python3#5). In Cloud Shell my project is deployed successfully (screenshot below). However, once I click on the link I get timeout. If I test it locally from Cloud Shell it works fine.

[image]

Why could this be happening? Where could I get more data about the issue?

Comment: What do you see in logs?Could you enable ESPv2 debug and look at the log of ESPv2 service?

Comment: @DivyaniYadav I ended up using App Engine, so this question isn't revelvant anymore. I'll probably delete it.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase timeout by clicking `EDIT & DEPLOY NEW REVISION` and then adjust new `Request timeout` value

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout) :

> For Cloud Run services, the request timeout setting specifies the time
> within which a response must be returned by services deployed to Cloud
> Run. If a response isn't returned within the time specified, the
> request ends and error 504 is returned.
>
> The timeout is set by default to 5 minutes and can be extended up to
> 60 minutes. You can change this setting when you deploy a container
> image or by [updating the service](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout#setting) configuration. In addition to
> changing the Cloud Run request timeout, you should also check your
> language framework to see whether it has its own request timeout
> setting that you must also update.

You can refer to this [Public group issue](https://groups.google.com/g/google-cloud-endpoints/c/xsrSkpCRmII) which will be helpful in resolving the current error.

Comment: @Nina is this answer helpful?